# Failure with improving Python nested where(str.contains)

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, lambda, nested

So I have a column called Job Type that has user input strings.  Data entry is supposed to stick to certain terms but with turn over oddities have been creeping in along with the normal misspellings.  I have a set of nested where statements that cleans up most of the strings.  However I am not sure of the long term efficiencies of this approach let alone the readability of the code as additional terms are added.  I thought I could convert it to lambda function that uses a dictionary of the terms and another lambda function in the dictionary to return anything I haven't thought of yet as the Job Type but I am getting a KEYERROR.

Working code is:

```
#Homogenizes Job Type
f_terms = ['FLOOR','FLR', 'TF', 'FT']   #List of common entries for FLOORS
w_terms = ['WALL', 'WL', 'TW' ]         #List of common entries for WALLS
c_terms = ['CAR','CPT']                 #List of common entries for CARPET
kbs_terms = ['KBS','BACKSPLASH']        #List of common entries for KBS (Kitchen Backsplash)
fire_terms = ['FIRE', 'FP', 'FRP']      #List of common entries for FIREPLACES
w_terms = ['WOOD', "WD"]                #List of common entries for WOOD
v_terms = ["VINYL", 'LVP','VP']         #List common entries for VINYL
pw_terms = ['PREWALK', 'PW']            #List of common entries for PREWALK
t_terms = ['TILE']                      #List of common entries for TILE (Generic Tile Repairs)
ft_terms = ['FINE', 'F/T']              #List of common entries for FINE TUNES

df['Job Type'] = np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(floor_terms)),"FLOORS",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(wall_terms)),"WALLS",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(carpet_terms)),"CARPET",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(kbs_terms)),"KBS",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(fire_terms)),"FIREPLACE",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(wood_terms)),"WOOD",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(vinyl_terms)),"VINYL", 
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(prewalk_terms)), "PREWALK",
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(tile_terms)), "TILE", 
                 np.where(df['Job Type'].str.contains('|'.join(ft_terms)), "FINE TUNE",
                          df['Job Type']))))))))))
```

Nonworking code is:

```
term_map = {
    'FLOOR|FLR|TF|FT': 'FLOORS',
    'WALL|WL|TW': 'WALLS',
    'CAR|CPT': 'CARPET',
    'KBS|BACKSPLASH': 'KITCHEN BACKSPLASH',
    'FIRE|FP|FRP': 'FIREPLACE',
    'WOOD|WD': 'WOOD',
    'VINYL|LVP|VP': 'VINYL',
    'PREWALK|PW': 'PREWALK',
    'TILE': 'TILE',
    'FINE|F/T': 'FINE TUNE',
    '.+': lambda x: x
}

pattern = re.compile('|'.join('(?:{})'.format(term) for term in term_map.keys()))
df['Job Type'] = df['Job Type'].str.replace(pattern, lambda match: term_map[match.group(0)] \
                 if isinstance(term_map[match.group(0)], str) else term_map[match.group(0)] \
                 (match.group(0)), regex=True)

*KEYERROR: 'WALL'*
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function instead of a `lambda` expression

```py
term_map = {
    'FLOORS': ('FLOOR', 'FLR', 'TF', 'FT'),
    'WALLS': ('WALL', 'WL', 'TW'),
    'CARPET': ('CAR', 'CPT'),
    'KITCHEN BACKSPLASH': ('KBS', 'BACKSPLASH'),
    'FIREPLACE': ('FIRE', 'FP', 'FRP'),
    'WOOD': ('WOOD', 'WD'),
    'VINYL': ('VINYL', 'LVP', 'VP'),
    'PREWALK': ('PREWALK', 'PW'),
    'TILE': ('TILE',),
    'FINE TUNE': ('FINE', 'F/T')
}

def get_kw(fullStr, ref_map=term_map):
    if fullStr in ref_map or not isinstance(fullStr, str): return fullStr
    for kw, lk in ref_map.items():
        # if re.match('|'.join(lk), fullStr): return fullStr
        for k in lk:
            if k in fullStr: return kw
    return fullStr

df['Job Type'] = df['Job Type'].apply(get_kw)
```

---

##### ADDED EDIT:

In retrospect, it might be better to just flatten the dictionary and use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead of using `.apply` with a function with a nested loop:

```py
# term_map = ... ## [ same as above ]
term_map_inv = {k: kw for kw, lk in term_map.items() for k in lk}

df['Job Type'] = df['Job Type'].str.extract(
    f'({"|".join(term_map_inv)})', expand=False
).map(term_map_inv).fillna(df['Job Type'])
```

or you could `.apply` the following version of `get_kw` that uses regex:

```py
def get_kw(fullStr, ref_map=term_map_inv, reg_pat = '|'.join(term_map_inv)):
    if isinstance(fullStr, str): 
        if (rsearch:=re.search(reg_pat, fullStr)): 
            return term_map_inv.get(rsearch.group(0), fullStr)
    return fullStr
```

[They seem to take about the same amount of time.]

Comment: Thanks for the help and the suggestion.  Finally got back to cleaning this up.  Your code resulted in an error, "type 'float' is not iterable for if k in fullStr: return kw"  However I was able to fix that by inserting an if instance(fullStr, str) statement at the start of the function.  Now that it is running that brings up another question.  This is slightly slower than the original nested wheres using str functions.  Is that because it is creating a function and the dataset is is somewhat small so efficiency will improve with a larger dataset or are str functions just more effecient?

Comment: @JamesOgle I've edited the string check into my answer; as for the timing, while `.apply` might seem to be a bit slower in general than most other Series methods (since it's calling an external function), I think the main issue is the nested loop inside `get_kw`. Regex seems to be faster, so I've suggested another method using it above